# cloned mac address not working

Tags: networking, network-manager, ifconfig

When I run `ifconfig` I see a specific mac address connected to my Ethernet connection.

So to change my mac address, I go to the topright where the internet connections are displayed, click on the **Edit Connections** option. Then I get the **Network Connections** popup, and I select the only **Ethernet** connection available and click the **Edit** button. From there I get the **Editing Wired connection 1** window, with the **Ethernet** tab selected. In the **Cloned MAC Address:** input, I place in the **NEW** mac address I want to use, and click save.

From there I use `ifconfig` again in the terminal, and I see that nothing has changed.

**QUESTION:** Why is the previous process not changing my mac address. :(

---

**UPDATE:**

Just to clarrify why this question is not a duplicate, the answer linked is outdated (2011) and the Ubuntu layout is no longer the same. You'll see a comment on that question from someone else saying that the answer in fact does not work anymore

Comment: May be all you need is restart...

Comment: Hi @George , the question/answer you linked is outdated (2011) and the Ubuntu layout is no longer the same. You'll see a comment on that question from someone else saying that the answer in fact does not work anymore

Comment: btw @George would you happen to know if there is a way to make the spoofing happen automatically on all connections? From what I understand, you first have to connect to attempt to connect to a wifi connection so that it appears in the list, and then edit the list manually all over again. I was wondering if a cloned Mac Address could be left as the default for all connections of a network interface?

Comment: @Webeng this might be helpful to you: [How to randomly change the MAC on each boot in 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914278/how-to-randomly-change-the-mac-on-each-boot-in-16-04/914286#914286)

Comment: thank you @Ravexina I will try that solution out and make sure to reply back here if it was successful or not :)

Comment: @Ravexina I just tried out your method! It worked however one issue was that I had to first try to connect to the WiFi connection before changing the Mac Address. Would you happen to know if there is a method to "globally" change the mac address? That way at no time is the Permanent Mac Address ever used.

Comment: @Webeng read the last part of [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Changing_Your_MAC_Address/Linux) link, it might work for you.

Comment: @Ravexina waw this could work! When I did `nano /etc/network/interfaces`, I got the following content: `# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)\n auto lo\n iface lo inet loopback` with `\n` representing each line break. Right now I'm looking into tutorials on iface stanza since the description of the link you presented says **place the following in the appropriate section of /etc/network/interfaces (within an iface stanza, e.g., right after the gateway line) **. If you happen to know what the code I would have to put there might be, I would love to know!

Comment: @Ravexina I actually made another question since this one isn't up to speed anymore. I would love it if I could get your feedback there. Here is the link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/917719/change-mac-address-permanently-inside-etc-network-interfaces