# Why is there no easy PERMANENT way to spoof your wifi Mac address on ubuntu?

Tags: networking, network-manager, ifconfig, nmcli

I apologize in advance for my feelings of unhappiness. I have been looking at all the alternatives out there to spoof my Mac Address on ubuntu. What I want is to spoof my Mac Address and for it to **stay** spoofed. I don't mind if I have to spoof it again after a reboot, But I do mind if I have to spoof it each time I make a new connection!

**What I've tried so far:**

- Macchanger: Works but I have to use it every time AFTER I make a connection
- nmcli: Works but I have to use it every time AFTER I make a connection
- GUI of the Network Manage (aka Cloned Mac Address): same as above
- ifconfig eth0 hw ether 02:01:02:03:04:08: same as above

**The only** option that might work is the one Thomas explained to me here: [Change Mac Address permanently inside /etc/network/interfaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917719/change-mac-address-permanently-inside-etc-network-interfaces)

Thomas's solution goes into the **/etc/network/interfaces** file and alters the Mac Address there. But by doing so, Network Manager no longer works, and you basically have to know how to do all the other parts (scan for wifi connections, connect to them, etc, etc) manually.

Now I am trying to understand what he did, and I'm still learning bits and peaces of it at a time. Though I still can't believe there isn't an easier solution.

**QUESTION:** Does anyone have a different solution? I don't mind if it has similarities with the previous solutions what so ever. I just want to be able to spoof my Mac Address once, and freely enter and leave any wifi connections I want without having to spoof it again. I don't mind if I have to spoof after reboots. I am loosing all hope, sorry if my frustration has spilled over into my writing.

Comment: Might want to look into udev rules ;-)

Comment: With NM >= 1.6, I would suggest https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/examples/nm-conf.d/30-anon.conf?id=260fd3e79f8decef7fd85c3ca00f6ec69dbe3678

Comment: heyy thaller this might be what I need! though after creating the file and rebooting, It doesn't work. Do I need to specify something else other than just creating that file in that location?

Comment: Is your NetworkManager version 1.6 or newer? Did you put the file to the right place? When enabling debug logging, NM will log the configuration at start. Does the connection profile have the corresponding properties unset, to allow for the fallback to the default?

Comment: Some drivers don't allow changing the MAC address. Does NM's logfile print warnings about that? Is macchanger able to change the MAC address? If not, it's a driver/hardware limitation

Comment: @thaller you seem to be right, the version is lower than 1.6, it's 1.2.6 atm. I tried however to upgrade it on ubuntu and ran by some issues. I made a new question on this, If possible I would love to hear your feedback https://askubuntu.com/questions/918311/network-manager-conf-file

Comment: could this help: https://github.com/jerabaul29/randommac together with the -c and possibly -p options?