# Network Manager conf file

Tags: networking, network-manager, configuration, ifconfig

I found a few sources explaining how it's possible to change your Mac Address via the Network Manager conf file:

**1) Create the following file:**

```
/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/30-anon.conf
```

**2) put the following script inside:**

```
[device-anon]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=yes

[connection-anon]
connection.stable-id=${RANDOM}
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=stable
wifi.cloned-mac-address=stable
ipv6.ip6-privacy=2
```

**Source:** https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/examples/nm-conf.d/30-anon.conf?id=260fd3e79f8decef7fd85c3ca00f6ec69dbe3678

Though after doing that, I restarted network manager, I rebooted the computer, but but when I used `ifconfig` to check the mac addresses associated with the ethernet and wifi, they were both the same.

**Question:** Why might the previous not have worked?

---

**UPDATE:** Regarding the version of NetworkManager:

`NetworkManager -v` gives me `1.2.6`. I tried doing

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to get the latest updates for my ubuntu, as well as

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade network-manager
```

and it said: "network-manager is already the newest version (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)." I am running Ubuntu and I don't understand why it's not upgrading to a higher version when using the previous methods. Am I using the wrong method?

Comment: The version of NetworkManager you have doesn't support it?

Comment: @muru `NetworkManager -v` gives me `1.2.6` I tried doing `sudo apt-get upgrade` to get the latest updates for my ubuntu, as well as `sudo apt-get --only-upgrade network-manager` and it said: "network-manager is already the newest version (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)."

Comment: Whereas the source code indicates the newest version of NM is at least 1.8.

Comment: would you happen to know what the command line would be to get the newest version? I've been looking for a way but without success